# jquery form submit using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want  to submit my form using ajax.

Below is my code:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function() {
var url = <url>;
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
            if(data == '0'){ 
                    $("#loginErr").show();
                    return false;
            }
            else if(data == '1')
                    return true;
       }
     });
  return false;
});
```

I want to get my form submitted if ajax response is 1. but irrespective of data value, form is not getting submitted. Its always getting return value false. I have checked it reaches to else if condition, but execution is not stopped on return.

How can I submit my form? I want to refresh my page.

Comment: AJAX is async btw you cannot return value from success callback function

Comment: Your **url** variable is an actual URL in your real code, correct?

Comment: please post your server side code...

Comment: @roasted, what can I do then?

Comment: @Aijaz, I have checked, it reaches to else if condition, but execution is not stopped.

Comment: You can call a method from your success function to do what you want rather than relying on a return value, or you can do whatever you want to do directly in success. Obviously don't forget to do something on fail.

Comment: Oh, and use === for comparisons

Comment: @MarkChorley, It reaches to else if condition, I want to refresh my page.

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {
    var url = < url > ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        context:this, //setting context on form
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '0') $("#loginErr").show();    
            else if (data == '1') this.submit();//use js submit event, not jq. We need to manually submit it now that we know its successful
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); //Stop the form submitting straight away
});
```

Comment: check if condition if (data == '1') is meet

Comment: what give you: console.log(this) inside this condition?

Comment: It says that its a form object

Comment: And removing this submit handler `$("#loginForm").submit(...)`, is your form submitted? What if you try $(this).off('submit').submit()?

Comment: Pls ignore my previous comment, It gives: Object { url=<url>, type="POST", more...}

Comment: Ok i really think you have forgotten to set context option of ajax

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which data you would like checked.  But if this data comes from the form itself, then you need to check it before ajax call. Once you make the ajax post call, your form is already submitted.

```
 $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) 
 {

 var url = <url>;
 e.preventDefault();
 mydata = $("#loginForm").serialize();
 //Your check here
 if(mydata == '0')
 { 
      $("#loginErr").show();
      return false;
 }

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: mydata,
   success: function(response)
   {
        //this is your post response processor
   }
 });
 return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted to refresh my page, I did want synchronous request. Setting async false solved the issue. I am able to get ret value outside Ajax object as it is requested synchronously.

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function() {
var url = <url>;
var ret = false;
$.ajax({
       async: false,
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            if(data == '1')
                    ret = true;
            else if(data == '0')
                    $("#loginErr").show();
       }
     });
     return ret;
});
```